# search a point of interest using GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, web-mapping, geoext, ext-js

I develop an application of webmapping using GeoServer, GeoExt and ExtJS. I want to search my points of interests (layer that exist in GeoServer) so i create a two combox where i have to put the categorie of my points of interest and the name of my point of interest(optional). My data base is in PostgreSQL.

Any idea guys of how i should proced ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publish your points with WFS service and make your client to build CQL Filters. If you are brave or want your application to work also with other WFS servers than only Geoservers you can use filters which are build according to the Filter Encoding standard of OGC. These CQL filter examples are hitting the demo server of Boundless and you will receive some real data if the server is up.

Select all states called 'Connecticut'

[http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&cql_filter=STATE_NAME=%27Connecticut%27](http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp%3astates&cql_filter=STATE_NAME=%27Connecticut%27)

Select all states called 'Connecticut' which have STATE_FIPS code '09'

[http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&cql_filter=%28STATE_NAME=%27Connecticut%27%20AND%20STATE_FIPS=%2709%27%29](http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp%3astates&cql_filter=%28STATE_NAME=%27Connecticut%27%20AND%20STATE_FIPS=%2709%27%29)

Select all states called 'Connecticut' which have STATE_FIPS code '08' (none will be found)

[http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp:states&cql_filter=%28STATE_NAME=%27Connecticut%27%20AND%20STATE_FIPS=%2708%27%29](http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp%3astates&cql_filter=%28STATE_NAME=%27Connecticut%27%20AND%20STATE_FIPS=%2708%27%29)

Reading about CQL filters is here http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I publied my layer with WFS service (GeoJSON) and it appear a page that contain the attributs of my layer. Now how can i build CQL Filters and how to integrate it to my application ?

Comment: Sorry, I have absolutely no experience on making web applications. Let's hope that some JavaScript coders will help you further. Meanwhile you can try to find something from the web.

Comment: finally it works for me !! i used CQL Filter as u said to me ! thank youuu.